# Select de uma linha no phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Boa tarde pessoal.

Quando desenvolvendo para VB eu utilizei um select utilizando o top, para selecionar determinada linha que eu queria, porém estou desenvolvendo em php agora e estou utilizando o BD do phpmyadmin e gostaria se possível como eu faço para selecionar somente uma linha, pois irei utilizar um loop no php para ir lendo linha por linha.

já testei o limit porém mostra todos dentro do limit, e preciso do select que selecione somente uma linha.

Testei alguns select que o pessoal comentou em vários sites mas sem sucesso.

o último que usei agora foi o:

```
`SELECT cdAgendamento FROM agendamento WHERE cdAgendamento > 10 AND ROWNUM = 1`
```

Grato!

Comment: pode limitar os resultados do select usando o limit.

Comment: Sua pergunta esta confusa. Você diz q quer selecionar somente uma linha no select. O "SELECT * FROM tabela limit 1"; faz isso. Mas ai depois vc diz que pretende fazer um for no PHP para ir lendo linha por linha. Vc quer trazer um ou mais resultados do MySQL?

Comment: Eu testo primeiro no select, pois quero ler linha por linha.

Comment: Por exemplo, preciso ler a linha 1 a 5, uma de cada vez e se no select ele trazer um de cada vez como quero depois no php faço o loop que vai lendo uma por vez.

Comment: @Anderson M. seus comentários ainda estão confusos para mim. Vamos ver se eu entendi. Você quer fazer um select de 5 registros e depois fazer um for no PHP para ler esses registros?

Comment: Eu quero simplesmente selecionar uma linha específica, por exemplo eu tenho 10 registros, e quero somente o registro 7, então queria saber como fazer, no SQL server eu utilizava o top q depois q vc usa o count para ter a quantidade de linhas eu seleciono a que eu quero pelo número entendeu.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa solução: http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/obter-equivalente-ao-rownum-do-oracle-para-o-mysql/30959

Answer (score 1):

Mysql vc pode usar o LIMIT.

```
SELECT cdAgendamento FROM agendamento WHERE cdAgendamento > 10 LIMIT 1
```